# SQL SERVER ODBC to MYSQL twin records different?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc

I have a SQL Server Store procedure that works as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyStoreProcedure]
(
    @manufacture_datetime DATETIME, 
    @string as varchar(4)
)
AS
    BEGIN

    .....
    insert into openquery([odbcsource],'select * from mytable') (manufacture_datetime,number) values (@manufacture_datetime,1)
    insert into openquery([odbcsource],'select * from mytable') (manufacture_datetime,number) values (@manufacture_datetime,2)
    .....
```

The procedure works perfect on almost all my servers however i found a server where sporadically  this insert ends up as:

```
    2015-01-06 11:49:40  1
    2015-01-06 11:49:39  2
```

Any thoughts on what can cause this twin records to have 1 sec difference? So far i have thought that maybe something on milliseconds is screwing something up but that seems a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird behavior, is it possible that you have some trigger that is setting the `manufacture_datetime` to current time on the MySQL side? Have you tried to insert it by one insert instead of two?

```
 insert into openquery([odbcsource],'select * from mytable') (
     manufacture_datetime,number
 )
 select
     @manufacture_datetime, v.number
 from (values (1), (2)) as v(number)
```

Comment: I have not tried use just one insert, i will definitively give that a try. On the trigger,  the timestamp variable is actually offset with when the record is created for about 30 seconds. And there are no triggers on the table :(